# Как подключить js файлы в расширение через Asets?

Tags: yii2

Собственно ни где не нашел в документации только исходя из примеров догадываюсь
что надо создать папку assets в расширении создаем файл `MyExtensionsAssets` наследуемся от `AssetBundle`, 
а вот дальше вопрос работать через свойства `css` и `javascript` или через метод `init()` и как подключить `jqueryUi`, и как подключить свой скрипт, и дальше ещё вопрос как подключать асеты вот так ?

```
MyExtensionsAssets::register($this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Папка assets уже есть в yii2
И дефолтный файл AppAssets тоже, он находится в roject_folder/frontend/assets (для шаблона advanced) или roject_folder/assets (для шаблона basic)

Вы правы, что бы подключить Asset, необходимо в layout'е вписать

```
use app\assets\YouAsset;
YouAsset::register($this);
```

Что бы подключить к нему свои css и js файлы, используются свойства

```
public $css = [
    '/css/you_css.css',
];
```

и

```
public $js = [
    '/js/you_js.js',
];
```

У yii2 с коробки уже есть bootstrap и jquery asset'ы

Что бы их включить используйте свойство

```
public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
];
```

Пример всего YouAsset.php

```html
namespace frontend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class YouAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $jsOptions = ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD];
    public $css = [

    ];
    public $js = [

    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

Comment: А причем assets уже есть в yii2 я же пишу о расширении?

Comment: https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/structure-assets/

Comment: конкретные ответы на мои вопросы в документации не указаны. Я уже читал и не понял как потому вопросы и задал.